# UINotificationFeedbackGenerator & UIImpactFeedbackGenerator doesn't work for me on iPhone6S / iOS 14.3. Does any body had the same issue?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I experienced a strange Haptic behavior on iPhone6S / iOS 14.3.

```
UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
&
UIImpactFeedbackGenerator()
```

don't produce any vibrations

while

```
 AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
```

do it.

I confirmed with the same simple code on an iPhone XR where both work.

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct ContentView: View {
    
      func simpleSuccess() {
           let generator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
           generator.notificationOccurred(.error)
      }

      func otherVibration() {
           print("#")
           AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
      }

      var body: some View {
           VStack {
                Text("UINotificationFeedbackGenerator")
                .onTapGesture(perform: simpleSuccess)
                .padding(.bottom, 60)
                Text("AudioServicesPlayAlertSound")
                .onTapGesture(perform: otherVibration)
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: What is your pregunta?  Is it "Does anybody have the same issue"?  Is it "How can I report the bug to Apple, Inc"?  Or is it "Is there a workaround"?

Comment: You're right @ElTomato. I completed my title according your proposal.

Comment: Click on 'supported models' at the following URL.  https://support.apple.com/en-hk/guide/iphone/iph07c867f28/ios

Comment: You would have been helped by this blog post of mine: https://www.biteinteractive.com/finishing-touches-haptics/

Answer (score 2):

According to [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-hk/guide/iphone/iph07c867f28/ios), not all models support the haptic feedback.  iPhone 6S doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good way to know if the model support or not haptics

```
import CoreHaptics

print(CHHapticEngine.capabilitiesForHardware().supportsHaptics ? "Yes" : "No")
```

Comment: Have you actually run your code?  If I run it with a simulator under iOS 14.4, I get 'No.'  I wonder if that's just the matter of running it with an actual device?

Comment: Yes I ran it on an actual device. It says 'No' as expected.